# Is it possible to create Tikz-based text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In one of my Tikz plots, I have created the a simple circle filled with red:

```
\addplot [mark=*, mark size=3, mark options={solid, fill=red}] coordinates {
(1.25, 0) };
```

Now I would like to refer to that circle in the text, so I was wondering if it's possible to create a command that when inline with text, reproduces the same circle.

**EDIT**

Posible solution almost works in Figure caption:

[image]

Comment: you mean draws the same shape outside the picture environment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The circle can also be drawn in TikZ; `plot` also accepts `mark` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\RedCircle}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\RedCircle}{%
  \tikz\path plot[
    mark=*,
    mark size=3,
    mark options={solid, fill=red},
  ] coordinates {(0, 0)};%
}
\begin{document}
Circle: \RedCircle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Vertical centering around math axis

The centered symbol fits better into parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\RedCircle}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\RedCircle}{%
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \tikz\path plot[
      mark=*,
      mark size=3,
      mark options={solid, fill=red},
    ] coordinates {(0, 0)};%
  }}}%
}
\begin{document}
Circle (\RedCircle)
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Bounding box correction

TikZ seems to forget to take the line width of the mark into account for
the bounding box. The following code adds a small frame to compensate this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\RedCircle}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\RedCircle}{%
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{.21pt}%
    % 0.2pt (half line width)
    % + 0.01pt to get some rounding tolerance
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \fbox{%
      \tikz\path plot[
        mark=*,
        mark size=3,
        mark options={solid, fill=red, draw=black},
      ] coordinates {(0, 0)};%
    }%
  }}}%
}
\begin{document}
% Show bounding box:
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
(\textcolor{cyan}{\fbox{\RedCircle}})
\end{document}
```

Adding the margin inside TikZ (maybe, the image gets clipped by externalizing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\RedCircle}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\RedCircle}{%
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \def\BoundingBoxCorrection{.55\pgflinewidth}%
    % .5\pgflinewidth: half the line width, forgotten by TikZ
    % .05\pgflinewidth: some tolerance for rounding errors
    \tikz\path plot[
        mark=*,
        mark size=3,
        mark options={solid, fill=red, draw=black},
      ] coordinates {(0, 0)}
      (current bounding box.south west)
      ++(-\BoundingBoxCorrection, -\BoundingBoxCorrection)
      (current bounding box.north east)
      ++(\BoundingBoxCorrection, \BoundingBoxCorrection)
    ;%
  }}}%
}
\begin{document}
% Show bounding box:
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
(\textcolor{cyan}{\fbox{\RedCircle}})
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Can I put this as a command in the preamble to use it many times?

Comment: Also, the code above doesn't work within a caption.

Comment: @aaragon TeX is a macro language. LaTeX has `\newcommand`. `\DeclareRobustCommand` can be used for robust macros that also work in moving arguments (`\caption`).

Comment: That still doesn't work because it is cut. See image in edit.

Comment: @aaragon My image clearly shows, that it is *not* cut. Thus, there seems to be additional code, that does the cutting. Make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Nevertheless, I have updated the answer to vertically center the circle around the math axis to better fit into parentheses.

Comment: That took care of it!